How to manipulate filter icon in DT with bslib bootstrap 5
I want to use bootstrap 5 with DT. When using bootstrap 5, DT looks better in general, but the filters get its remove icon misplaced (see circle below filter field). In addition a "new" remove icon (X) is seen only when field is active (focused), in the original position of the circle icon (comparing with bootstrap 3).
I want to know if there is a way to relocate the circle icon to its original position keeping bootstrap 5, or if there is a way to manipulate the "new" remove icon, to make it permanent and also replace it with another icon.
Hiding the circle icon only is possible but not enough as a valid answer.

# Load required libraries
library(shiny)
library(bslib)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = bs_theme(
    version = 5,
    bootswatch = "cosmo",
  ),

  titlePanel("Shiny App with bslib/bootstrap5 and DT"),
  mainPanel(
    DTOutput("data_table")
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  data <- data.frame(
    Name = c("John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo"),
    Instrument = c("Guitar", "Bass", "Guitar", "Drums"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )

  # Render DataTable
  output$data_table <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      data,
      filter = "top",
      options = list(
        pageLength = 5,
        autoWidth = TRUE,
        dom = "Bfrtip"
      )
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)



to make it permanent: What do you mean with this? That the icon is always visible, also if the input is cleared and not in focus?

Yes, being permanent would be a good start for me to do further manipulations. So yes, a good answer makes it permanent and changes it to another icon

Is your goal that you have it always visible in your final app or what do you mean by further manipulations? I am asking because I think that it is not easy to always show the icon, one may need a custom implementation of the input. Removing the old icon is easy and replacing the default icon with another one is also easy.

To have an icon when no filtering/selection and a different icon otherwise

Maybe try https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/1098#issuecomment-1817937014.

In your app code, add the following to use the sass package (which is installed with bslib) to help you customize you theme with scss (pretty much the same as css)
library(sass)

Replace the ui by the following:
ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = bs_theme(
    version = 5,
    bootswatch = "cosmo",
  ) %>%
    bs_add_rules("
    /* align icon */
    .dataTable * .form-group {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }
    /* force not hiding icon */
    .dataTable * .form-group > span {
      display: inline !important;
    }
    "),
  
  titlePanel("Shiny App with bslib/bootstrap5 and DT"),
  mainPanel(
    DTOutput("data_table")
  )
)

Basically your form-group is composed of two elements: an input and a span. So you select any form-group inside a dataTable, no matter how many levels it's nested in with .dataTable * .form-group and you style it as a flex-box to manipulate how both elements are placed.
Also, the icon is managed with events and when the form is empty (no filter) the span is styled with display: none;. To show it permanently, simply force it to another value than none, like display: inline !important;. The !important tag will bump up this styling in the hierarchy and force it to use it instead of the default display: none.
Alternatively, if you have more scss styling to do, create the file styles.scss inside the www/ folder in your directory, put the following code:
/* align icon */
.dataTable * .form-group {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
/* force not hiding icon */
.dataTable * .form-group > span {
  display: inline !important;
}

/* more styling */

then use bs_add_rules(sass_file("www/styles.scss")) instead of the scss styling as a string.
In general you can inspect your app webpage and try to manipulate elements directly on the browser to see if it achieves what you want, then add it to your theme with scss code.
Regarding the change of icon, I'm not too sure as the span for the icon has the glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle class which uses that icon from the glyphicon library - you'd have to somehow change the class I guess?
